# calling c# method from tag inline

Tags: c#, asp.net

how i get this work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server" src='<% getSrc("ddd") %>' ></script>
```

getSrc is a method in code-behind file.

tanks.

Comment: Could you add the code for `getSrc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src='<%= getSrc("ddd") %>' ></script>
```

1. Don't use runat="server"
2. <%= MethodName("Parameter") %>

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= getSrc("ddd") %>" ></script>
```

Comment: @AVD I took it out, I doubt it has any value, since there isn't even an Id.

Comment: got exception: 
Parser Error Message: Illegal characters in path.

Comment: Probably needs to be `src='<%= getSrc("ddd") %>'`

Comment: It causes the error that r.zarei mentions above (illegal characters in path) because the parser gets mixed up by the consecutive double-quotes.  I've made that mistake many times =)

Comment: @jadarnel27, the parser is confused only when you use `runat="server"`. The example provided here doesn't have it and it should work.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Wow, you are correct (as usual).  My mistake, sorry Yuriy!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use (see the equal symbol next to "<%"):

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server" src='<%= getSrc("ddd") %>'></script>
```

Without the equal symbol, the methods is called but its result is never printed in the HTML code.

Comment: Same answer as @Yuriy Faktorovich: he was faster than me!

Comment: No, it's not the same. @Yuriy Faktorovich's answer is more correct as he removed the uselesss `runat="server"` attribute from the script tag.

Comment: Yeah, that's right: I've just done a copy/paste without really looking at the code.

Comment: got exception Parser Error Message: Illegal characters in path.

Comment: What does output your getSrc method ?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the method in the code behind is `protected`. Only `public` and `protected` methods can be called.